# event.stopPropagation() is not working as expected in react 17.0.1?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I am using click listener on parent node which closes the dropdown when it's got clicked parent body but in my dropdown, there is an input tag. When I opening dropdown focusing on input tag for writing parent node click listener gets triggered which closes the dropdown

```
<div onClick={this.doSomething} classsName="parentNode">
    <DropDown>
        <section className="input_wrapper">
           <input onFocus={(e)=>{
                     e.stopPropagation()
                     console.log(e.isPropagationStopped())}} 
                     onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
        </section>
    </DropDown>
</div>
```

In input `onFocus` event gets triggered and `e.stopProgation()` also triggered `console.log(e.isPropagationStopped())` is logging true in console but the problem is parent node event still gets triggered.

Comment: Using `stopPropagation()` doesn't mean that *every* event won't bubble up. In this case only the `focus` event won't bubble. You'll need an `onClick` handler and call `stopPropagation` in that if you want to prevent the `click` from bubbling.

Comment: exactly i was going to say, maybe it's not `focus` that got bubbled up, I would first check `click`. Unless you are only trying to deal with tabbing.

Comment: thanks, @EmielZuurbier its worked as expected sorry for the silly question.